# How to count number of characters before a specific character?

Tags: c++

I'm playing around on my spare time with C++ and I can't for the life of me seem to figure out how to count the number of characters before a specific one in a String.

For example:

```
Hello My Name \t is Bob!
```

I want it to count the number of characters (including spaces) before `\t`.

Here is my attempt:

```
std::string test = "Hello My Name \t is Bob!"
std::string::size_type pos = line.find("\t");
int numOfCharacters = 0;

while (pos == std::string::npos) {
    numOfCharacters++;
    pos = pos + 1;
}
```

My understanding of `.find()` was that if `npos` was retrieved, that means you didn't find the text you were looking for, so I assumed it would keep going until I found `\t` so it would kick out of the while-loop.

Comment: What do you want `numOfCharacters` to be if the character you are looking for in the string is not there in the string?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your understanding of `find()` is correct, but your use of `npos` is wrong.

If the substring *is* found, you don't enter the loop, and `numOfCharacters` remains 0.

If the substring *is not* found, you loop without regard to the string's content until `pos` eventually increments to the point where it becomes `npos` (-1), and `numOfCharacters` will end up with a value that is nowhere near correct.

Maybe you were thinking of something more like this?

```
std::string test = "Hello My Name \t is Bob!"
std::string::size_type pos = line.find("\t");
std::string::size_type i = 0;
int numOfCharacters = 0;

while (i < pos)
{
    numOfCharacters++;
    i = i + 1;
}
```

That would be redundant, though.  A string is 0-indexed, so a given character's index is *also* the number of characters that preceed it.  You don't actually need a loop at all if you use `find()`:

```
std::string test = "Hello My Name \t is Bob!"
std::string::size_type pos = test.find("\t");
int numOfCharacters = static_cast<int>(pos);
```

If you are going to loop manually, then dont use `find()` at all:

```
std::string test = "Hello My Name \t is Bob!"
int numOfCharacters = -1;

for(std::string::size_type pos = 0; pos < test.size(); ++pos)
{
    if (test[pos] == '\t')
    {
        numOfCharacters = static_cast<int>(pos);
        break;
    }
}
```